# How do you write a direct sum of two vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

I get the crux of the topic. However, every example I see of writing direct sums seems so arbitrary. Take problem 1C21 on http://math.ucdenver.edu/~langou/5718/nelsen/HW1.pdf      I don't understand how it can be established that every element of $W$ is $(0, 0, x_3, x_4, x_5)$ in the second line and then say that $(0, 0, x_3 - x_1- x_2, x_4 - x_1 + x_2, x_5 - 2x_1)$ is also an element. What rules or axioms allow you to say that?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I couldn't figure out latex on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$W$ is defined as the subspace 
$$
W:=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\x_3\\x_4\\x_5\end{pmatrix}~:~x_3,x_4,x_5\in F\right\}.
$$
Here are used $x_3$, $x_4$ and $x_5$, but those are not fixed values, but free variables within the definition. Maybe it is easier to interpret $W$ as the subspace where the first and second component has to be $0$ while the third, fourth and fifth component is some arbitrary value in $F$.

Now consider some fixed values $x_1,\ldots,x_5$ and the vector
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
x_3-x_1-x_2\\
x_4-x_1+x_2\\
x_5-2x_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
How does this vector looks like? The first and second component is $0$ while the third, forth and fifth component is just some values in $F$. Therefore this vectors is contained in $W$ by definition of $W$. The values $x_1,\ldots,x_5$ comes from the choice of $(x_1,\ldots,x_5)\in F^5$ and are **not** related to the definition in $W$.

On the other hand
$$
U=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}x1\\x_2\\x_1+x_2\\x_1-x_2\\2x_1\end{pmatrix}~:~x_1,x_2\in F\right\}
$$
has to be interpreted as the subspace where the first and second components are arbitrary values in $F$ but the third component has to be the sum of the first and second, the fourth has to be the difference of the first and second and the fifth has to be two times the first components. Here is the fomula in the third, forth and fifth components important!